# Chest deformation low poly

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting, topology

This is my low poly

Here a shot

[image]

Don't look hands, i'm finishing it these days.
I would like to understand one thing, making me crazy.
I'm trying to check if my low poly was made well for animation (topology of vertices, the shape of muscles in particular the back the shoulders and the chest/pectorals)

Now it seems working all pretty well except one thing: **PECTORALS and AREAS NEAR THEM**

Here the situation

[image]

If i move my upper arms down the deformation is this one

[image]

Now it isn't so impressive but **the mesh of chest goes inside the shoulder in point 1 and in point 2 it deforms inside the body.** I have tried weight paint but i don't think it's the definitive solution. I have doubts for my mesh and vertices.

Now my question is:

1)Is a problem of topology? (i have followed a very useful tutorial for doing that [in particular this picture](http://www.hippydrome.com/ModelingArm.html)) Too few vertices? I think 5800 for a low poly was too much^^

2)Is a problem of my mesh: did i make pectorals too bad, too large or something near the chest isn't right?

Can someone help me??

**Here the link of my file**

[image]

Comment: Download an already rigged character and study how it is done. It should be from someone that knows his stuff. A lot of tutorials are actually done wrong. You can try the gooseberry or sintel characters, they are free.

Comment: Can you give me a link? Thank you for the information

Comment: Start here: https://durian.blender.org/news/sintel-lite/, it's a fairly simple rig. For the gooseberry they are on the blender cloud and a video walk-through is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLzCSzfQe8A

Comment: The gooseberry rig can be downloaded from here: https://gitlab.com/jpbouza/BlenRig

Answer (score 2):

That should be a weightpainting problem.
As far as I can see you have more than enough mesh for the deformation in that armpit area and your geometry looks clean, too. 
Weightpainting can be a pain in the butt and takes a lot of time to get it right.
I never weightpainted in Blender, but usually 3d programs can display the weights in different colors so you can see more clearly what's going on with your weights.

Hope this helps you a little :)

Comment: I tried to work with weight paint in blender and of course the colors help a lot . . . but i can only move the weight from a vertex to another. More weight here or less and so on . . .  The point is that these part of mesh should deform not stronger or waker . . . the deformation should be different at all . . . that's make me crazy. Anyway thank you for your answer

Comment: I have a thought. I once saw a tutorial for rigging in Cinema 4D. What the author did was add extra bones for buttocks and scapulas so they behave naturally and preserve volume. Maybe you need to work on your rig instead of the skin? Just a thought.